Where is the Firebase functions container image after deployment
I used Firebase Deploy to deploy a few functions to Firebase Functions. I can see that underlying it is simply Cloud Run in the GCP Console. However, when I attempted to redeploy directly in Cloud Run to change some networking configurations, I get an error that the container image is not found.
It seems that Firebase deploy, in an attempt to save money, deletes the Cloud Build containers after deployment, and so in Artifact Registry, the container image isn't there. It is so weird to me though, because if you check the YAML file for the Function (in Cloud Run), you will see a reference to a container image in Artifact Registry but it is not actually there.
So if someone can help with either:

disable the container image cleanup/delete post deployment

or

find exactly where is the container image that is currently hosting the service

Thank you for your help

You can disable the automatic cleanup that the Firebase CLI does of the images by running:
firebase experiments:disable deletegcfartifacts

See PR #6861 and PR 6927.

thanks, actually this flag plus the automaticallydeletegcfartifacts would do it
